# Drupal versus Joomla: Which one has a better performance better?

Tags: performance, drupal, joomla

I have a project need to start in a week; Joomla and Drupal are both in my candidates list. Performance is the key to my project: Which one do you think is better for me?

Comment: Define performance. Quick response time? Lots of concurrent connections? Dynamic or static data?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal is better supported for high load sites than Joomla. It is also much more flexible. I've built sites on both and I wouldn't touch Joomla again tbh.  Companies like Turner Media run sites like "Cartoon Network" on Drupal, albeit highly customised and thoroughly beefed up.

If you're using Drupal 7 it has a lot of these customisations built into the core and so will absolutely fly along on all but the biggest projects.

Check out the Drupal High Performance Group if you have any specific questions.
http://groups.drupal.org/high-performance If you can't use D7 because it doesn't have the modules you need, then D6 is pretty well supported for large site now, would recommend looking at [PressFlow](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale) as a distribution - it's coded from the ground up for high performance sites.

TBH your hardware setup will have more of an impact on performance. If you're running your site on some 2-bit shared hosting then it'll be a pig - if you're running on an array of dedicated servers with [PressFlow](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale), [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) caching, dedicated database servers etc, it'll fly.

Answer (score 1):

That might be a question depending on several factors. Mainly which caching options are offered (usually by 3rd party plugins) Im not much of a fan of Joomla. By your question it sounds like you are new to building a CMS. Have you looked into Wordpress? Very easy to work with and tons of plugins. I would go with that or Drupal.

I realized in the end I didnt really answer your question that well either. To be honest I wouldnt focus on the performance of the CMS you decide to use. There are so many tweaks you can do to apache, IIS, lighttpd, nginx, etc... Also disabling modules and running a lean DB will help out greatly. But since we all like pictures links and quotes here is one that should help http://buytaert.net/drupal-vs-joomla-performance

Answer (score 1):

Well, others have spoke up for Drupal, I have to say I'm a big fan of Joomla.
If you're new to CMS Joomla has much less of a learning curve - and despite statements to the contrary - is just as capable as Drupal for running large/popular sites.

There are quite a few similarities between the two.
For more 'programmy' folks, they seem to really jump into Drupal and like it because it requires a bit more knowledge in that arena to use out of the box.  Joomla can be very programmy oriented for the advanced users, or it can be simple to use out of the box (a bit unlike Drupal) for the average user who just wants a nice clean site up quickly.

Both of them have little things that make them unique, but both are completely capable and very similar 'under the hood'.  If you do some research between them you'll find in very specific testing - each out performs the other for various specific tasks.  If those tasks are important to you, then weigh those tests appropriately.

If you're just a general user looking to make a great site?  Joomla has a much more simple/straightforward learning curve and Drupal is more 'programmer' oriented out of the box - but both are good solutions.

I personally choose Joomla - I'm familiar with the framework and can make any sort of custom template/site up and running in short order.  Drupal seems to always make me invest more time in customizing modules, having to figure out exactly how to get modules to do what I want them to, etc.  Joomla has a huge community (thousands of modules) that typically have a lot of parameters out of the box to get them to work as designed.

Just my $.02!  Either way, you won't go wrong if you already have a bit of php knowledge.